# Django, not able to load template through TEMPLATE_DIRS

Tags: python, django

im a begginer in DJANGO.. i was creating my first template and trying it to load into my view through get_template(). But it shows an error "TemplateDoesNotExist at /time/". i don't know what im doing wrong. these are my files.

------------settings.py-----------

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'cg@&q^y)&nvn=te*h!)ax#t4@=_t#phjr_4cr)+8xs$s7iwtir3'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'pr1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'pr1.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

TEMPLATE_DIRS=[

    '/home/sidharth/Desktop/projects/project1/pr1/pr1/templates'
]
```

-----------urls.py-------------

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from views import current_date_time
from views import hours_ahead
urlpatterns = patterns('',
            (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
            (r'^time/$',current_date_time),
            (r'^time/(\d)/$', hours_ahead ),

            )
```

------------views.py-----------

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.template import Template, Context
from django.template.loader import get_template

# Create your views here.
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime
def current_date_time(response):
    now=datetime.datetime.now()
    t=get_template('time.html')
    time=t.render(Context({'time':now}))
    return HttpResponse(time)
def hours_ahead(response,offset):
    offset=int(offset)
    final_time=datetime.datetime.now()+ datetime.timedelta(hours=offset)
    final="<html><body>the time after %s hours will be %s</body></html>" %(offset,final_time)
    return HttpResponse(final)
```

---------------time.html------------

```
<html><body>It is now {{ time }}.</body></html>
```

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [official release django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/upgrading/), in version 1.8 things have changed regarding how templates parameters are configured.

`TEMPLATE_DIRS` has been deprecated, so you can remove it from `settings.py`.

Instead, in `TEMPLATES`, set the `DIRS` key correctly (it is empty now).

For example:

```
TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'), ], # check the path depending on your prj structure
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```